# print datagrid cell value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with printing. I want to print cell in print document. My problem is if one row you can read it but if multiple row all string value is on the same x and y position. how can i achieve adding x and y in every row?

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim pn As String = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        Dim des As String = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        Dim quan As String = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString
        Dim pcs As String = ("PCS")
        Dim pri As String = row.Cells(4).Value.ToString
        Dim total As String = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString


        Dim x1 As String = 10
        Dim y1 As String = 185
        Dim z1 As String = ("   ")

        Dim x2 As String = 60
        Dim y2 As String = 200
        Dim z2 As String = ("              ")
        Dim z4 As String = ("       ")
        Dim z5 As String = ("                    ")



            e.Graphics.DrawString(pn + z1 + des, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, x1, y1)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(quan + z4 + pcs + z2 + pri + z5 + total, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, x2, y2)

    Next
```

Comment: change `x1` and `y1` in your loop if you want them to print in different places.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: how can i achieve it? pleas can you help me?

Comment: Read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you so much. i just solve my problem. thank you so much.

Comment: doing your own printing engine is going to lead to more problems...not recommended

Comment: Noted Sir. Thank you so much